# Java RMI Compute Engine

Tags: java, parallel-processing, task, rmi, distributed-computing

I am following the [Java RMI tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html) from here to build an example compute engine where the clients can submit tasks to a known server, and which the server will perform the task and return the result.

Having compiled and created new tasks sucessfully I want to learn further by reversing the logic, i.e. the server sends the task to the clients.

How would I conceptually do this?  If I have understood correctly, the RMI server exposes the executeTask() method, which a client calls upon connecting to the server.  I am toiling with turning each client into a 'server', each running an RMI registry and another application will connect to each of the rmi registries and call the executeTask method, and thus download the class.

Is there an obvious apporach in the logic I am missing? Having multiple RMI registries seem's incorrect.

What I want to end up with is a server with exposed RMI registry.  All clients connect to server, server calls executeTask() method on each client to process the task on the clients.  Ofcourse the task class needs to be located at the server and downloaded dynamically to the clients (currently the task is located at the client and sent to the server).

Answer (score 0):

Have the server expose a `fetchNextTask()` method, and have the clients call it when they're ready to perform another task.

Comment: thanks for the response.  So are you saying my approach to have each of the clients hold the RMI logic is the right appraoch?  I am having difficulty putting down on paper, what functionlaoty will be held where.  If you are familiar with this tutorial or problem area, could you expand further the archeture I should be going for?

Comment: No. Don't put words into other people's mouths. I have told you how to implement the question you asked. Whether it's a good idea is a completely different question which I haven't said anything about whatsoever. I've given you all the 'architecture' you should need.

Comment: Calm down, no one is putting words in your mouth.  It was a question to see if am approaching the problem correctly.  Your 'answer' wasn't sufficent for me as a begginer.  However, thanks for stopping by.  Do carry on.

Comment: *You* are putting words into my mouth. That's what questions of the form 'so are you saying' always do. In my extensive experience, the answer to questions of that form is invariably 'no'.